# wait for while loop to end before executing code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve data from an object, I generate 3 random numbers from 1-9 and then pick out data from a json object using these random numbers. However it sometimes works and then sometimes doesn't, I think it might be because it doesn't wait for the random numbers to be generated before selecting data from the object, it all occurs on page load:

the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dbqw79j4/1/

the code:

```
var jsonfile =[      
        {
        "id" : "article1",
        "image" : "http://images.domain.com/is/image/boss/BOSS_london_bridge_skyline?$c_overview_large$",
        "headline" : "<h2>EIN TAG IN LONDON<span class='h2'>MIT LEWIS HAMILTON</span></h2>"
        },
        {
        "id" : "article2",
        "image" : "http://images.domain.com/is/image/boss/FAB_5819?$c_overview_large$",
       "headline" : "<h2>EIN TAG IN MONACO<span class='h2'>MIT NICO ROSBERG</span></h2>"
        },
  ...
]

var arr = []
var article1;
var article2;
var article3;

var art1hd;
var art1img;

var art2hd;
var art2img;

var art3hd;
var art3img;


while(arr.length < 3){
  var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*9)
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
  }
  if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
console.log(arr[2]);


article1 = arr[0];
article2 = arr[1];
article3 = arr[2];

console.log(article1)
console.log(article2)
console.log(article3)


art1hd = jsonfile[article1]['headline'];
art1img = jsonfile[article1]['image'];

art2hd = jsonfile[article2]['headline'];
art2img = jsonfile[article2]['image'];

art3hd = jsonfile[article3]['headline'];
art3img = jsonfile[article3]['image'];

console.log(art1hd)
console.log(art1img)

console.log(art2hd)
console.log(art2img)

console.log(art3hd)
console.log(art3img)
```

Comment: What is the error when it does not work?? Is it "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'headline' of undefined"..?

Comment: Check the fiddle. `TypeError: jsonfile[article3] is undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generate random numbers from range of 0-9 and your array contains only 9 elements and it is indexed from 0-8

You should use:

```
while(arr.length < 3){
  var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*8)
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
  }
  if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
}
```

Comment: Good catch! Just one note - `Math.ceil()` is not the right function to use with `Math.random()` in this fashion. It should always be `Math.floor()` instead - see my answer for details on this issue. The correct formula here would be `Math.floor( Math.random() * 9 )`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, your "jsonfile" array has nine elements. this breaks when you generate the random number 9, as arrays are zero-based, the valid values for indexing the array are 0-8

Answer (score 1):

`Math.ceil()` is never the right function to generate an integer result based on `Math.random()` times something as this code does:

```
var randomnumber = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 9 );
```

You should always use `Math.floor()` in code like this instead. If you don't want your range to start with 0, then add the range base after doing the `Math.floor()`.

In other words, if you want a random integer in the range 1 through 9 inclusive, this is the correct way to do it:

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 9 ) + 1;
```

Why is this? It's important to understand that `Math.random()` produces a value that is greater than *or equal to* 0, and less than (but never equal to) 1.

So `Math.random() * 9` gives a value that is always less than 9 (and never equal to 9). If you take `Math.floor()` on that, you now have an integer in the range 0 through 8 inclusive.

Add 1 to that, and you have your desired range of 1 through 9.

Many JavaScript references fail to describe `Math.random()` clearly. Just keep in mind that its result is in the range `0 <= Math.random() < 1`.

So, what could go wrong if you used `Math.ceil()`? Going back to the original example:

```
var randomnumber = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 9 );
```

What this code actually does is generates a number in the range 0 through 9, not 1 through 9. Now the chance of getting a 0 result is extremely small: it would be fairly rare for `Math.random()` to return 0, but it *can happen*. By using `Math.floor()` instead, you insure that the result is *always* in the desired range.

That said, as suvroc points out, you're (eventually) using this value as an index into an array of 9 elements, therefore the range you want is actually 0 through 8. So the code should be:

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 9 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is, because the random number generator can generate the number 9, but your `jsonfile` has only 9 elements, so the last index is 8.

Answer (score 0):

First, as others said the random number generated as to be :

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*9)
```

Then I reviewed the code to be sure of synchronicity :
http://jsfiddle.net/dbqw79j4/6/

I did a recursive function who calls logs on `arr.length >= 3` and add a random number if it doesn't exists on arr.